# get category with child categories next to it

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a categories table.

Categories

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.categories
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('categories_id_seq'::regclass),
    name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    description text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    shell text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    createdat timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now(),
    "isChild" boolean DEFAULT false,
    "motherCategory" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" DEFAULT 'none'::text,
    CONSTRAINT categories_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

im looking for an output similar to this:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| motherCategory                                        | childCategories                                     |
+----+----------+---------------+----------+------------+----+---------+--------------+----------+------------+
| id | name     | description   | shell    | createdat  | id | name    | description  | shell    | createdat  |
+----+----------+---------------+----------+------------+----+---------+--------------+----------+------------+
| 1  | mother 1 | mother 1 desc | m1/shell | 13/12/2013 | 2  | child 1 | child 1 desc | c1/shell | 01/01/2014 |
|    |          |               |          |            +----+---------+--------------+----------+------------+
|    |          |               |          |            | 3  | child 2 | child 2 desc | c2/shell | 6/9/2069   |
+----+----------+---------------+----------+------------+----+---------+--------------+----------+------------+
| 4  | mother 2 | mother 2 desc | m2/shell | 01/02/2033 | none                                                |
+----+----------+---------------+----------+------------+----+---------+--------------+----------+------------+
| 5  | mother 3 | mother 3 desc | m3/shell | 11/11/2011 | 6  | child 3 | child 3 desc | c3/shell | 05/05/2005 |
+----+----------+---------------+----------+------------+----+---------+--------------+----------+------------+
```

its a fairly complex query, well atleast for my level, basically my categories table has both mother and child categories in one place, and differs them with two columns (isChild: boolean, motherCategory: integer), isChild lets sql know that category is a child, and motherCategory stores the id of the mother category located in the same table.

as for the query i think its self explanatory, basically i want to show a list of categories where every mother category is stored next to all its children, displaying all their data aswell, and incase a mother doesn't have children, it returns none as the child element.

> To be completely honest im new to sql, so im not even sure if an
> output like this is possible, but incase you have any idea, help me
> out!

Thanks

Please help me if you have any ideas

Answer (score 0):

As per my opinion You should separate two table for mother and child

I am assuming that motherCategory is having id of mother of particular child

So your expected output can be generate by below query

```
SELECT 
m.id, m.name, m.description, m.shell, m.createdat
,c.id, c.name, c.description, c.shell, c.createdat
FROM 
(SELECT id, name, description, shell, createdat,motherCategory FROM categories WHERE isChild=0)m LEFT JOIN
(SELECT id, name, description, shell, createdat,motherCategory FROM categories WHERE isChild=1)c
ON m.id=c.motherCategory
```

Comment: after some tweaks it worked fine. thanks very much